# 400 error with HttpClient for a link with an anchor

Tags: java, android, anchor, httpclient

Here is my code:

```
DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
```

This works for every url I have tried so far, except for some urls that contain an anchor.  Some of these anchored urls return a 400. The weird thing is that it isn't all links that contain an anchor, a lot of them work just fine.

Unfortunately, I have to be really general as I can't provide the specific urls here.

The links are completely valid and work just fine in any browser, but the HttpClient returns a 400 when trying the link.  If I remove the anchor it will work.

Any ideas what to look for?

For example:  `http://www.somedomain.com/somedirectory/somepage#someanchor`

Sorry again for the generics

EDIT: I should mention this is for Android.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Greg Sansom says, the URL should not be sent with an anchor / fragment.  The fragment part of the URL is not relevant to the server.

Here's the expected URL syntax from [relevant part](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html#sec3.2.2) of the HTTP 1.1 specification:

```
    http_URL = "http:" "//" host [ ":" port ] [ abs_path [ "?" query ]]
```

Note: there is no `fragment` part in the syntax.

What happens if you do send a `fragment` clearly is server implementation specific.  I expect that you will see a variety of responses:

- Some servers will silently strip / ignore the fragment part.  (This is what you are expecting to happen).
- Some servers might treat this as a request error and respond with a 400.
- Some servers might mistakenly treat the fragment as part of the path or query, and give you a 404 or some other response, depending on how "confused" the fragment makes the server.
- Some servers might actually imbue the fragment with a specific meaning.  (This strikes me as a stupid thing to do, but you never know ...)

IMO, the most sensible solution is to strip it from the URL before instantiating the `HttpGet` object.

**FOLLOWUP**

The recommended way to remove a fragment from a URL string is to turn it into a `java.net.URL` or `java.net.URI` instance, extract the relevant components, use these to create a new `java.net.URL` or `java.net.URI` instance (leaving out the fragment of course), and finally turn it back into a String.

But I think that the following should also work, if you can safely assume that your URLs are all valid absolute HTTP or HTTPS URLs.

```
    int pos = url.indexOf("#");
    String strippedUrl = (pos >= 0) ? url.substring(0, pos) : url;
```

Comment: Do you know what is the best method for removing a fragment from a url?

Answer (score 5):

Your usage of the anchor in the url is incorrect.
When we perform a "Get", we need to get the entire resource (page).  The anchor is just a tag marking a location, normally your browser will scroll to the position of the anchor once the page is loaded.  It does not make sense to "Get" the page at a specific anchor - the entire page must be fetched.

It is possible your inconsistent results are because some web servers are ignoring the anchor component, and others are correcting your error.

The solution is just to remove the #anchor portion of the url before running your code.

Comment: This is exactly correct; the anchor is not a valid URL part to send to a web server.

Comment: I was just trying to leave the url as is, but this makes sense, since it won't be used anyways.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

String user_url2="uhttp://www.somedomain.com/somedirectory/somepage#someanchor";

```
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet siteRequest = new HttpGet(user_url2);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    HttpResponse httpResponse;

    try {
        httpResponse = client.execute(siteRequest);
        HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        InputStream in = entity.getContent();

        String line = null;
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(in));
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)

        {

            sb.append(line);

        }

        result = sb.toString();
```

result string will display url value

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in Android HttpClient that was fixed in HttpClient 1.2 but not backported to Android

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HTTPCLIENT-1177

https://github.com/apache/httpclient/commit/be6347aef0f7450133017b775113a8f3fadd2f1c

I have opened a bug report at:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=65909