# HTTPClient - HTTP GETs broken with a # anchor in a redirect URL

Tags: java, httpclient, http-get

This is a bit of a weird one. I'm using HTTPClient 4.1.2, and it seems that whenever it finds are URL with something like a '#' in it, it does a full get with the # in the URL.

For example, trying to get the URL `http://stks.co/eWt` will redirect to the URL `http://news.ichinastock.com/2011/10/jack-ma-alibaba-has-prepared-20-billion-to-acquire-yahoo/#.Tpw-xG61XjU.twitter`. Now this URL is live, but the problem is the HTTPClient sends a get request with the URI set to  `URI: /2011/10/jack-ma-alibaba-has-prepared-20-billion-to-acquire-yahoo/#.Tpw-xG61XjU.twitter` which causes the server to send back a 404 page not found.

Looking at the GET sent by IE, Firefox and cURL, they all strip out the #... from the end of the URI, so for example the cURL GET request URI is set as URI: `/2011/10/jack-ma-alibaba-has-prepared-20-billion-to-acquire-yahoo/` - all the #... have been removed. This is for the exact same entry URL of `http://stks.co/eWt`.

As a test, sending this raw URL into HTTPClient (i.e. `HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://news.ichinastock.com/2011/10/jack-ma-alibaba-has-prepared-20-billion-to-acquire-yahoo/#.Tpw-xG61XjU.twitter");`) gives the same 404 not found result.

So the question is are there any settings in HTTPClient that can be set so that things like the trailing #... can be auto removed from URLs. Or how would I go about manually removing this from URLs (remember that I would need to capture all redirect URLs as well)?

Comment: This could help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4251841/400-error-with-httpclient-for-a-link-with-an-anchor

Comment: Yeah I saw this one. But the problem is I dont know if the URL has an # anchor in it. All the URLs are comming from a short URL service, this short URL service keeps the #anchor in the URL, and HTTPClient blindly takes this from the redirect 301 and tries to get the page...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like their web server is broken. The URI specification says that a number sign (#) terminates the path portion of the URI. If a web server considers anything after a # part of the path, it is not following the URI specification.

> The path component contains data, usually organized in hierarchical form, that, along with data in the non-hierarchical query component, serves to identify a resource within the scope of the URI's scheme and naming authority (if any). The path is terminated by the first question mark ("?") or number sign ("#") character, or by the end of the URI." - [RFC3986](http://labs.apache.org/webarch/uri/rfc/rfc3986.html)

I tested a few popular web servers, and they all parse these URIs correctly, ignoring the portion after the number sign.

I don't have any good suggestions for a workaround though. But at least now you know who to blame.

Comment: Thanks David, this is definitely a web server thing. But we are crawling a number of sites (all which I'm sure have a plethora of doggy servers). So a simple work around might be in order. It would seem that cURL, IE and FF all strip it out so they dont need to worry about server impl...

Comment: I'd suggest modifying the HTTPClient source code. Add a hook into the redirect logic where it calls your code and gives it a chance to modify the URL. I realize it's ugly, but you're working around someone else's problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** All strings coming after the hash (and the hash) won't be sent to a server. The hash in URL's is meant for browsers to work with and not a server.

Comment: tried this one. The issue is its a redirect. The URLs come from a short/tiny URL service and redirect, so I dont know if the redirect URL is going to have a #anchor in it or not... I would need a way to capture the redirect URL as well. Also its very much a server specific thing as to how they deal with the # in a URL. It would seem that cURL, IE and FF all strip it out so they dont need to worry about server impl...

Comment: That will make the part after the number sign part of the path, creating the very problem he's trying to solve.

Comment: @NightWolf I think it is going to have an anchor, but the server would strip it out. See http://tinyurl.com/68mkvcc

Comment: Arguably the # anchor is not valid to send to a web server and thus one could say a way to get HTTPClient to handle this (remove the anchor) would be helpful...

Comment: How will URL-encoding the # help? when it isn't supposed to be sent? and the server doesn't recognize it.

Comment: Trying things that won't work is pointless, as is recommending them.